# Request inside a nested request loop to another server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to request X products from another server and I need to wait for that execution to finish before proceeding and saving the order in the database.
Let's say I receive via post an array of product Ids that I need to add to the order, e.g

```
JSON FILE:
{
   "order_products":[1,2,3,4]
}
```

Here's a code sample:

```
//Express module
var router = require('express').Router();
//HTTP Request module
var client = require('request');
//Util that saves the URLs of the other databases
var productURL = require('../utils/product/productURL');
//Builds a product object given a JSON 
var productBuilder = require('../utils/product/productBuilder');

router.post('/', req, res) {

//Instantiate a new order
  var orderInstance = new order({
       date: Date.now
  });

//Query the products in the other server and add them to the order
  req.body.order_products.forEach(id => {
       client.get(productURL.HTTPS + id, { json: true }, (err, res, JSONProduct) => {
                var product = productBuilder.build(JSONProduct);
                orderInstance.order_products.push(product);
      });
  };

//Save the order in the database
  orderInstance.save(....);

//Send response
  res.status(201).json(orderInstance);
}
```

The problem here is that while the loop is still executing, the response is sent (201) and the orderInstance is saved without any product. If I console.log the products they only appear after the orderInstance is saved.
I've tried implementing callbacks to fix this issue, but with no success. I'd appreciate if anyone could lend me a hand here! Thanks in advance :smiley:(edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` runs *synchronously* - when the `forEach` ends, the `client.get` requests may have all been sent out, but the responses surely haven't come back yet. You need to convert each request into a `Promise`, and then call `Promise.all` on an array of those Promises. The `Promise.all` will resolve once all responses have come back. For example:

```
const allPromises = req.body.order_products.map(id => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  client.get('productURL.HTTPS' + id, { json: true }, (err, res, JSONProduct) => {
    if (err) reject (err);
    else resolve(productBuilder.build(JSONProduct));
  });
}));
Promise.all(allPromises)
  .then((newProducts) => {
    orderInstance.order_products.push(...newProducts);
    res.status(201).json(orderInstance);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle errors
  });
```